# error: ‘logFileObj’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors, g++

I have a file named `global.h` whose contents are:

```
#define DEPTH 10
#define LOGGING     //to log the progress of the program.
#ifdef LOGGING
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
extern std::string logFileName;
extern std::ofstream logFileObj;
#endif
```

Also `main.cpp`:

```
#include "global.h"

using namespace std;

#ifdef LOGGING
string logFileName = ".log";
ofstream logFileObj;
logFileObj.open(logFile);    //line 13
logFileObj<<"depth: "<<DEPTH<<endl;    //line 14
#endif
```

I am constantly getting the following error in compilation:

```
src/main.cpp:13:1: error: ‘logFileObj’ does not name a type
src/main.cpp:14:1: error: ‘logFileObj’ does not name a type
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: is `logFileObj.open(logFile);` in function?

Comment: @billz I got the mistake. It was not in function. As I understand it, main should be the first function to be called and that was the error here. Am I correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ does not allow operation outside function. C++ allows you define variable globally but you need to put operations inside functions.

If I read your question correctly, you just need a function and call it when you need to:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
void WriteLog(const std::string& log_file_name, const std::string& prefix, const T& data)
{
  std::ofstream log_file_handler(log_file_name.c_str(), std::ios::app);  // if you use C++11, you could use string directly
   log_file_handler << prefix << data << std::endl;
}
```

usage:

```
WriteLog<int>("app.log", "depth:", DEPTH);
```